# How can I copy image from one project to another?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have two different projects in GCP and I created useful image in project 1. I want to have this image in project 2. How can I do it?

Answer (score 25):

I found a solution.

```
gcloud compute --project=project2 images create image-2 --source-image=image-1 --source-image-project=project
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also create image from **Google Cloud Console**

From your new destination project, select **Create Image** ans select **source == image** (See screenshot)

[image]

Comment: This does not allow you to get the image from another project.